# Upload dependency to different maven repo

Tags: maven, maven-3

I already build my project with maven where some the artefacts are put in private Nexus, others are in public.maven

Is there an easy way to upload my dependency to new repository or something like that.

**My goal** is to put only required artefacts from my private nexus repo to new repo.

Comment: What do you mean by "required artifacts"?

Comment: I mean the dependency artefacts that are in my Nexus

Comment: Sorry, what are "dependency artifacts"? Could you please be more explicit what you want? Could you add an example to the question?